# Deriving len/min/sum of dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have the following dictionary for which I’d like to produce a new dictionary that gives the original keys but the values are computed using len, min and sum.

```
scores = {
    "Monday" : [21, 23, 24, 19],
    "Tuesday" : [16, 15, 12, 19],
    "Wednesday" : [23, 22, 23],
    "Thursday": [ 18, 20, 26, 24],
    "Friday": [17, 22],
    "Saturday" : [22, 24],
    "Sunday" : [21, 21, 28, 25]
}
```

I initially tried to use the following but it only returns a single value:

```
for k, v in scores.items():
    stat = {
        k : [len(v), min(v), sum(v)]
    }
```

This returns: `{'Sunday': [4, 21, 95]}`

Doing some research, I managed to use the following comprehension to achieve the outcome:

`stats = {k : [len(v), min(v), sum(v)] for k, v in scores.items()}`

This returns:

```
{'Monday': [4, 19, 87], 'Tuesday': [4, 12, 62], 'Wednesday': [3, 22, 68], 'Thursday': [4, 18, 88], 'Friday': [2, 17, 39], 'Saturday': [2, 22, 46], 'Sunday': [4, 21, 95]}
```

I would really like to understand why my first attempt only produced a single value and didn’t iterate through the entire dictionary?

I’m new to learning Python so very keen to understand the difference in methods and what I was doing incorrect with the first method.

Many thanks!
JJ

Comment: Because each time you go through the loop you overwrite the value of `stat`. What you wanted was to initialise `stat` to an empty dictionary before the loop, then use `stat[k] = [len(v), min(v), sum(v)]` (or perhaps use `.update`) in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
for k, v in scores.items():
    stat = {
        k : [len(v), min(v), sum(v)]
    }
```

is the equivalent of doing:

```
stat = {"Monday" : [len(scores["Monday"]), min(scores["Monday"]), sum(scores["Monday"])}
stat = {"Tuesday" : [len(scores["Tuesday"]), min(scores["Tuesday"]), sum(scores["Tuesday"])}
...
stat = {"Sunday" : [len(scores["Sunday"]), min(scores["Sunday"]), sum(scores["Sunday"])}
```

On each iteration of the loop, you're re-assigning `stat` to a new single-item dictionary.  The last one is `Sunday`, so that's the final value that `stat` has after the loop is finished.

If you did something like:

```
stat = {}
for k, v in scores.items():
    stat[k] = [len(v), min(v), sum(v)]
```

your end result would be an accumulation of all the values, similar to the result you get from the dictionary comprehension (which is generally the preferred way of building a dictionary through iteration).

Answer (score 0):

your script is iterating arround all dictionary

but you are overriting the result dictionary

try something like:

```
stats = []
for k, v in scores.items():
    stat = {
        k : [len(v), min(v), sum(v)]
    }
    stats.append(stat)
print(stats)
```